# Fragment with viewmodel bound to an activity being used in multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, architecture, viewmodel

Currently I have a fragment class with a viewmodel being used in multiple activities. The viewmodel(viewModelOne) was added to be used in Activity1 but when Activity2 uses the fragment there is a runtime exception since the fragment's viewmodel is scoped to be used in the activity(eg. ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()) and Activity2 doesn't instantiate viewModelOne. The easy solution is to create the viewModelOne instance in the Activity2 class but i am not a fan of this solution since viewModelOne is not relevant for this activity class. Any other solutions or recommendations?

Comment: Maybe if you provide the ViewModel via dependency injection, it's instance won't be in the activity but in that current scope, so you can inject it in the fragment directly. Does your project uses dependency injection?

Comment: If the same fragment with that ViewModel is being used across both Activity1 and Activity2, then doesn't that imply that the VM is relevant in both?  You have the same fragment used in two separate Activities so a ViewModel that supports that fragment should be available to both.  Now if you're concerned that the ViewModel contains fields that are only specific to Activity1 then maybe you should split it to two ViewModels - one that's just for the fragment and can be shared with Activity2 and the other VM that is just for Activity1